# TYPO3 folder is not found in TemplaVoila directory

Tags: windows, windows-7, typo3, templavoila

I started using TemplaVoila plugin in TYPO3, and I am facing a problem in the installation.

When I click over "Start the mapping process button", a 404 error is shown with the message: /typo3conf/ext/templavoila/typo3/index.php was not found on this server.

I searched for this file, and I realized the /typo3 folder does not exist.

I am using Typo3 4.6 and TemplaVoila 1.6 in Windows 7

Has anyone had this problem as well? thanks!

Comment: Do you run it with XAMPP on Windows 7?

Comment: Just to get updated: Are any of these answers working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something went wrong with the paths configuration here. `/typo3conf/ext/templavoila/typo3/index.php` is not supposed to exist at all. Here's some steps you might to try.

- Did you define a `General Record Storage Page`? [Howto](http://templavoila.busynoggin.com/download/installing-tv-framework-in-a-typo3-dummy-package/#c767)
- Try reinstalling the TemplaVoila extension
- Try older versions of TemplaVoila
- Try to get it running in TYPO3 4.5

It might be a bug as TYPO3 4.6 was released recently.

Answer (score 0):

Templavoila 1.5.5 and above doesn't work with Color TV.